# Crystal Report can't find specified path file

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I am trying to install my developed VB.net application in the client machine, I have built up some report forms using Crystal reports it works fine in my PC. But on client machine it shows error

Crystaldecisions.crystalreports.engine.reportdocument threw an exception

When I click on details in the error message
It shows the path was not found 
The directory is still pinging to my system
C:/user/mydocuments/admin/application name/bin/debug/report file

But I have also installed the Crystal report runtime 13.0.5 which I have used for development

My coding to open crystal reports file path in VB.net

```
Dim rptdocument as new reportdocument

On load event
rptdocument.load(Application.StartupPath&"\filenname.rpt")
```

Comment: The key question is to ask if the file is definitely in the application startup path folder. Also, I notice that the file name you supply in your question has 2 letter "n"s, so the next question is if the spelling is correct. To make sure that the path is what you expect it is, set a break point on the `rptdocument.load` line and inspect the value of `Application.StartUpPath`, copy the value and paste the path into Explorer to open that folder to see if your file is there.

Comment: I would also suggest that instead of `Application.StartupPath & "\filenname.rpt"`, try `Path.Combine(Application.StartUpPath,"filenname.rpt"`. It will make sure that you have the right number of slashes etc.